# Create a folder in a directory with a variable in the path (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I am looking to create a function that when ran it creates a new time-stamped folder in my current working directory with two subfolders (input and output).  My Python skills are non-existent (never used it before).  I can make the time-stamped folder, but how do I best create the subfolders without having to hard code the path name?

```
from os import mkdir
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now

new_run = 'H:\model\{}' .format(today().strftime('%d%m%Y'))
mkdir(new_run)

inputfold = 'H:\model\\19072017\{}' .format('input')
outputfold = 'H:\model\\19072017\{}' .format('output')
mkdir(inputfold)
mkdir(outputfold)
```

Instead of having `inputfold = 'H:\model\\19072017\{}' .format('input')` I want the variable name in place of the time stamp so that each new day the model is ran you do not have to manually change the path `inputfold = 'H:\FSM IV\\***today***\{}' .format('input')`.  I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from os import mkdir, makedirs
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now
new_run = r"H:\model\{}" .format(today().strftime('%d%m%Y'))
makedirs(new_run+"\input")
makedirs(new_run+"\output")
```

Comment: Thank you! What does adding the "r" in front of the path do?

Comment: @JonSnow Placing the `r` in front of a string literal makes it a "raw string".  If your path was `H:\model\tables`, then without the `r` at the front Python would interpret `\t` in "\tables" as the tab character, which is not what you want. In a raw string, special characters (such as `\n`, `\t`, etc.) are not special and there is no worry about accidentally creating a tab or newline where you didn't mean to .  The alternative `r'H:\model\tables'` would be `'H:\model\\tables'` which is more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using string formatting, I am a HUGE fan of using built-in functionality to do this. You can either use `os.path` or `pathlib`, both in the standard library (`pathlib` from Python 3.4 onwards).

Using `os.path`

```
import os.path
from os import mkdir
from datetime import datetime

# No need to wait to call the function... do it now!
today = datetime.now()

# Make the time stamp.  Here I am demonstrating you can
# Do the formatting with the .format operator directly.
time_stamp = '{:%d%m%Y}'.format(today)
# Alternatively
#time_stamp = format('{:%d%m%Y}', today)

# Create the path names.
# Variables can be used directly! No need to worry about
# using raw strings or escaping the '\' character!
new_run = os.path.join('H:', 'model', time_stamp)
inputfold = os.path.join(new_run, 'input')
outputfold = os.path.join(new_run, 'output')
# Alternatively to the above
#inputfold = os.path.join('H:', 'model', time_stamp, 'input')
#outputfold = os.path.join('H:', 'model', time_stamp, 'output')

# Create!  os.makedirs is also good.
mkdir(new_run)
mkdir(inputfold)
mkdir(outputfold)
```

Here is how you might do it using `pathlib`

```
import pathlib
from os import mkdir
from datetime import datetime

# No need to wait to call the function... do it now!
today = datetime.now()

# Make the time stamp.  Here I am demonstrating you can
# Do the formatting with the .format operator directly.
time_stamp = '{:%d%m%Y}'.format(today)

# Create the path names.
# Variables can be used directly! No need to worry about
# using raw strings or escaping the '\' character!
new_run = pathlib.Path('H:', 'model', time_stamp)
# pathlib lets you use the / operator to build paths. Super cool!
inputfold = new_run / 'input'
outputfold = new_run / 'output'

# Create the folders, ensuring all parents are also created.
inputfold.mkdir(parents=True)
outputfold.mkdir(parents=True)
```